# Function to return the geometric mean of numbers up to n

Tags: python

```
def geometric_mean(n):
    x = []
    b = list(range(n))
    for i in b:
        p = (i*i)**2
        x.append(p)
        return x
```

Comment: First of all `(i*i)**2 == i**4` which is not what you want. Also, you don't want to return from function in the first iteration of the for-loop.

Comment: You almost certainly want to dedent the `return` so the `for` loop can complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Calculate the geometric means of an array of numbers, we need to first multiply all the numbers in the array all together. Then we will need to take the nth root of the product to get the mean.

```
def geometric_mean(n):
    num_list = [num for num in range(1, n + 1)] # num_list = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]
    product = 1 # set the product to 1
    for num in num_list: # multiplies all the numbers together in num_list
        product *= num
    mean = product ** (1 / n) # take the nth root of product to get geometric mean
    return mean
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gives the geometric mean of the sequence of numbers from 1 to n.

```
def geometric_mean(n):
    b = list(range(1, n+1))
    p=1
    for i in b:
        p = p*i
    return p**(1/n)
```